# require file as string

Tags: string, node.js, express, require

I'm using node + express and I am just wondering how I can import any file as a string. Lets say I have a txt file all I want is to load it into a variable as such.

```
var string = require("words.txt");
```

I am against

```
modules.exports = function(){

    var string = "whatever";

    return string;

}
```

Comment: It's not an answer, but this avoids creating a function: `const { string } = require('words.js');` where `words.js` contains `module.exports = { string: 'whatever' };`

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If it's for a (few) specific extension(s), you can add your own [`require.extensions`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions) handler:

```
var fs = require('fs');

require.extensions['.txt'] = function (module, filename) {
    module.exports = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
};

var words = require("./words.txt");

console.log(typeof words); // string
```

Otherwise, you can mix [`fs.readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback) with [`require.resolve`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve):

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readModuleFile(path, callback) {
    try {
        var filename = require.resolve(path);
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', callback);
    } catch (e) {
        callback(e);
    }
}

readModuleFile('./words.txt', function (err, words) {
    console.log(words);
});
```

Comment: require.extensions is now deprecated for anyone who comes across this post. http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions

Comment: `Deprecated in the past` but `Since the module system is locked, this feature will probably never go away. However, it may have subtle bugs and complexities that are best left untouched.`

Comment: While it is indeed deprecated, is there any good alternative? (that extends require, I mean)

Answer (score 60):

To read the CSS file to String, use this code. It works for `.txt`.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const css = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'email.css'), 'utf8')
```

ES6:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

let css = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'email.css'), 'utf8')
```

Comment: How can I get this done for an html file? i have an html file in a sibling directory that i need to read and load as a string into cheerio?

Comment: It works exactly the same for an html file:

const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../path/to/file.html'), 'utf8');

Answer (score 10):

The selected answer is **deprecated** and **not recommended** anymore.
NodeJS documentation [suggests](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_extensions) other approaches like:

> loading modules via some other Node.js program

but it does not expand any more.

- You can use a very simple library like this: [require-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-text)
- Or implement it yourself ( like from the package above: )

  > ```js
  > var fs = require('fs');
  > module.exports = function(name, require) {
  >    return fs.readFileSync(require.resolve(name)).toString();
  > };
  > ```

Answer (score 7):

you'll have to use `readFile` function from `filesystem` module.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readFile

Answer (score 6):

My simplest solution is

```
var string = require("fs").readFileSync("file.txt", 'utf8')
console.log("string = ", string);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can require .json files, both with node.js and TypeScript. That's the only format that support being required() suitable for serializing text. YOu can use a compile-time tool to pack your files into a json, such as https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/fs-to-json