# React.js load markdown file from system as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I would like to load a markdown file from the current directory as a string,  use case:

```
import { State } from "markup-it"             ;
import markdown  from "markup-it/lib/markdown";
import bio  from './Bio.md'


const mdParser = State.create(markdown);
const bio_o = mdParser.deserializeToDocument(bio);


// tried this next: but cannot import files system because react stubbed it out
const fs = require('fs');
```

When I `import bio from './Bio.md'` I get path to file, not a string format.  So next I try using the file system `fs` a la : [require file as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752622/require-file-as-string) but apparently `fs` has been stubbed out by react. So now I am completely stumped in terms of how I can import a file from the file system as a string. Am I missing something conceptually here? is it because I'm on the client side?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2961) has some information, you might have to eject if you're using create-react-app and modify the web.config to use a [raw loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) and use it's syntax in your import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fine bundling the markdown text in with your client app code, you can just stick [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) into your setup and tell webpack to apply it to anything ending matching `/\\.md$/i`, that would let you use `mdParser` on the client side.  This presumes of course that `Bio.md` is in the same folder as this JS file during build time.

If you want the client to load the markdown from the server and parse it then, you're back to what Rohith Murali said about fetch/axios.

### Edit: Setup

Setting up raw-loader to do this is really easy, as shown [right in their readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader#getting-started):

Installation is thankfully straight forward, unlike some modules they didn't need to do anything funny with the name.

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Then you configure webpack to load markdown files using the newly installed loader:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // new rule: anything ending with ".md" is loaded with raw-loader
      {
        test: /\.md$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      },
      // any other rules...
    ],
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Then just import your MD file as usual and get back a string:

```
import bio from './Bio.md';
const bio_o = mdParser.deserializeToDocument(bio);
```

Comment: I think  I will bundle the `md` files with the JS file during build time. could you provide a more fleshed out example please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I think you are missing something conceptually. When you build a react application and the user's browsers try to run your js the filesystem will be refering to the user's machine. But what you actually want is a file residing in the static server.
Two things can be done,

1. Eigther you can add the file to your src folder and do an import
2. Or you can do a fetch/axios call to get the file from your static server, in which case you will get the data in the call back function of your fetch/axios call