# Import .html file as a string in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I would like to be able to import .html file as a string template in NestJS application.
In order to satisfy TypeScript I created text.d.ts like this:

```js
declare module "*!text" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

and imported it in a file like this:

```js
import html from 'src/templates/test!text';
```

There are no complains from TypeScript. However when I try to run the
application I get the following error:

```sh
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^
    
Error: Cannot find module 'src/templates/test!text'
```

How to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you tried to use relative path instead of this absolute `'src/templates/test!text'`?

Comment: @MicaelLevi In the import the path is relative.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that's because you run compiled code from `dist/` folder and `.html` files are not copied from `src/`.

If so, you need to add these lines into `nest-cli.json` (`"compilerOptions"` section):

```
    "assets": ["src/**/*.html"],
    "watchAssets": true,
```

(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673191/1760643 answer, see [NestJS docs about assets copying](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets))

**Upd**: also `import` doesn't work for me.

[Used this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12753026/1760643):

`requireAsPlainTextConstructor.ts`:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

export default function requireAsPlainTextConstructor(dirname: string) {
    return (filePath: string) => {
        const filename = path.resolve(dirname, filePath);
        return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    };
}
```

Target file:

```
import requireAsPlainTextConstructor from 'requireAsPlainTextConstructor';

const requireAsPlainText = requireAsPlainTextConstructor(__dirname);
const myHtml = requireAsPlainText('my.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have written "test!text" I think it should be "test.txt" ( as I think you have saved it as a text file in your project and importing as RAW and using).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the error is the same.