# Node: read and parse HTML

Tags: html, node.js, html-parsing

Yo!
Lets say i have some index.html like this:

```
<span>Hello</span>
<span>mr.Goover</span>
```

I also have an app.js where I need to read index.html and store each of these 2 html lines in an object (as strings!):

```
const html = {
    greeting: '<span>Hello</span>',
    name: '<span>mr.Goover</span>'
}
```

The problem:
I can read index.html and store the entire content from it as a string:

```
const content = fs.readFileSync('/index.html').toString()
```

But I need to separate those 2 lines and put them in the correct objext fileds.
Can I do it without using html-parsing npm packages?

Comment: If this is the entire extent of the project - you will only ever have two sets of simply formatted `<span>` tags, then you can just use any number of simplified ways to parse this.  You could use a regex or you could use `.indexOf()` to find the different pieces.  If the content can actually be real HTML with all the assorted attributes and other tags, then for goodness sake, use a real HTML parser.

Comment: And, since the HTML contains no info at all about what is a `greeting` and what is a `name` or what might be some other property, you'd have to provide that info too.

Answer (score 0):

Manually? Sure.

```
const please_dont_do_this = content.split('\n');

const html = {
    greeting: please_dont_do_this[0],
    name: please_dont_do_this[1],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12753026/16602311).

```
const fs = require('fs');

require.extensions['.html'] = (module, filename) => {
  module.exports = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
};

const content = require('./index.html');

const [greeting, name] = content.split('\n');

const html = {
    greeting,
    name,
};
```

Comment: Dude I can read the file as string. The problem is to split the string correctly.

Comment: @Ishimura_Hideo You can try this: `content.split('\n');`. Answer has been edited.